# In the game Rise and Fall, is there any way of getting the population cap above 5000?

Tags: rise-and-fall

I have always wanted these massive all-out wars in *Rise and Fall*, but with the population cap at **5000**, there are no real way of accomplishing this, especially when playing against more than one person/ AI. Is there any possible way of increasing the maximum population cap above 5000?

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQs section](http://raf.heavengames.com/raf/gameinfo/faq) on the fan page states:

> The population cap is currently 5k. This may be subject to change as the game nears release.

Seeing how old the game is already, it's unlikely that it will change.

[This website](http://www.ggmania.com/cheat.php3?cheat=14451) (although it doesn't look reliable) says that numpad7 allows for unlimited people. As its worded:

> NUMPAD7 - Zero Population, causes you to build huge armies and citizens 
>   above the max population count. Unlimited people;)

Not quite sure how it works, and logically it doesn't sound correct (zero population?), but it's worth a shot.  I haven't found any other ways to exceed the population limit.

Comment: Unfortunately the numpad 7 didn't work, but thanks for the imput!